# Do we need an identify-this-actor tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Seeing as to how identifying actors [based on a single image](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15397/name-of-uncredited-actress-non-speaking-extra) or a description is apparently considered on topic, shouldn't we have an identify-this-actor tag?

Comment: It existed before. Might be deleted due to less activity or poor response to the question having that tag.

Comment: Hopefully not!!

Comment: Pointless, simple as that :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't get many questions like that, and if I recall correctly they have been closed in the past by people that have a greater sensitivity for trivia than me.

I don't see any reason why we wouldn't have such a tag.

Comment: OK, I'll add the tag. Thanks. Two questions have been asked about actor identification in the last day or so. [This](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15414/what-is-the-real-name-of-kate-daniels-bride-in-mr-beans-wedding) is the other one (albeit OT). [I don't think tags are deleted unless they are not used by any question. We have plenty of one-question-only tags, don't we?]

Comment: @coleopterist - there is some form of timing out of tags, if they are not used enough they are automatically deleted, but it may be as long as 6 or 12 months before this happens.

Comment: It must be [longer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sucker-punch) than [12 months](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/existenz).

Comment: @iandotkelly Doesn't this only apply for no-question tags. Otherwise this could cause serious trouble on a site with so many rarely used one-question tags as this one.

Comment: @coleopterist - I did some research, tags used only once are removed after six months.  If this is the only tag on a question it gets the 'untagged' tag.  So if we use the tag twice we're good.

Comment: @coleopterist. Mmm - I see your point about the 'more that 12 months'.  I cannot explain that about sucker punch. I found my information in this MSO post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121191/what-are-all-the-reasons-a-tag-can-be-eliminated-automatically perhaps its out of date.  We have had examples of tags being removed in the past.

Comment: It's possible that the routine is not triggered in beta sites.

Comment: @coleopterist - it has run in the past here, I remember us discussing whether we should re-apply tags that were removed. Perhaps its run manually and not on a schedule.

Comment: If that is true, then the practice of not having movie names in question titles might be fraught with risk. Weird.

Comment: I remember this to have come up earlier and I think it was even explicitly disabled for this site (mainly because of the title-tag policy, I think).

Comment: @coleopterist - i think the example you found shows that its not an issue any more, I don't remember the explicit disabling that Christian recalls, but clearly its no longer active.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks.